# Bifurcation analysis of subsystem

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm confused about a question in dynamical systems, and whether it can be done at all.

Say we consider the lorenz system

$
\dot{x} = \sigma(y-x)\\
\dot{y} = x(\rho-z)-y\\
\dot{z} = xy-\beta z
$

And we seek to do a bifurcation analysis, but we are for other reasons only interested in the bifurcation of the subsystem $\lbrace\dot{x},\dot{y}\rbrace$. How can we analyse this? Do we then consider $z$ to be a fourth parameter, which is time dependent?

Ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't work like that: either $z$ "matters" or not, and in the first case it isn't possible to do what you want.

> Luckily $z$ actually doesn't matter in this equation, at least a the origin, in the following sense:

When one linearizes the system, the third equation becomes $z'=-\beta z$. Since $\beta$ is usually assumed to be positive, this doesn't contribute to any bifurcation.

On the other hand, the linearization of the first two equation doesn't include the variable $z$ and you can check that there is a bifurcation at $\rho=1$ passing from a saddle to a sink.

This bifurcation is also (necessarily) present in the full linearization and so also in the original equation (because it goes from a hyperbolic equilibrium to a hyperbolic equilibrium).

Comment: Would it be possible to look at the dynamics in the poincare section spanned by the $xy$-phaseplane?

Comment: That's an entirely different question, how does it relate to **your** question?

Comment: Maybe my formulation was clumsy, I'm interested in the dynamics in the $\dot{x}\dot{y}$-phaseplane. In doing a bifurcation analysis of this subsystem.

Comment: Would you agree that I have already replied to **your** question?

Comment: I don't think so. I wanted to do a bifurcation analysis of the subsystem $\dot{x}\dot{y}$ and asked if this was possible, which you wrote wasn't. Then I asked if planting a poincare section in the $\dot{x}\dot{y}$-phaseplane and considering the dynamics in this poincare section wasn't excactly what I wanted to do?

Comment: OK, good luck then. Next time you might be more appreciative after getting a complete reply such as mine. Might get more attention... Also, you need to study, a lot.